# How to stop TopAppBar scrolling when the content is not scrolling

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying out the `scrollBehavior` for `TopApp` with `Scaffold`. Here is the code

```
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text(
                    "TopAppBar",
                    maxLines = 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )
            },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                        contentDescription = "Localized description"
                    )
                }
            },
            actions = {
                // RowScope here, so these icons will be placed horizontally
                IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                        contentDescription = "Localized description"
                    )
                }
                IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                        contentDescription = "Localized description"
                    )
                }
            },
            scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
        )
    },
    content = { innerPadding ->
        LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = innerPadding,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            val list = (0..5).map { it.toString() }
            items(count = list.size) {
                Text(
                    text = list[it],
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
)
```

The TopAppBar scroll collapses and expands even when the contents are not scrollable.
How do we avoid the TopAppBar scrolling behaviour if the contents are within the window and there is no need for scroll behaviour??

**EDIT**:

Instead of `LazyColumn`, I am using `Column` with `.verticalScroll(scrollState)`.  How do we avoid the TopAppBar scrolling behaviour if the contents fit on the screen and there is no need for scroll behaviour??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JanItor. His comment helped me to resolve my issue. Following is the way I have modified my `scrollBehavior`.

```
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState(),
        canScroll = {
            scrollState.canScrollForward || scrollState.canScrollBackward
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

The necessity for scrolling can be derived from a `LazyListState`, similar to [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#correct-usage) example:

```
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val canScrollTopBar by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0 || listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset > 0
        }
    }
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(
        canScroll = { canScrollTopBar }
    )
```

And don't forget to set `state` in `LazyColumn`:

```
        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
```

**Edit**: Actually, i don't think `derivedState` is necessary here, `canScroll` lambda will be called anyways, so it's OK to just put the logical expression directly into `canScroll` lambda.

```
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(
        canScroll = { listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0 || listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset > 0 }
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. Is there any way to do the same if I have `Column` instead of `LazyColumn`?

Comment: For a scrollable `Column` you will have to provide a `ScrollState`. If you declare it like `val scrollState = rememberScrollState()` you can check `scrollState.canScrollBackward` or `scrollState.canScrollForward`.

Comment: @Nik forgot to tag you, check my previous comment.

Comment: `scrollState.canScrollBackward` or `scrollState.canScrollForward` works perfectly. Thank you @JanItor

Here is the way I have used it.

```
`val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState(),
        canScroll = {
            scrollState.canScrollForward || scrollState.canScrollBackward
        })`